# Wrike API using Python

Tags: python, api

I am trying to use Wrike API with Python. I am unable to get the access token. I am pretty new to ouath2 via API so not sure where I am going wrong, any help is highly appreciated

```
import json
import os
import requests
import time
import logging
from time import localtime, strftime

wrike_url = "https://wrike.com/"
wrike_user = "username"
wrike_password = "password"
wrike_clientId = "clientid"
wrike_clientSecret = "secret"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('wrike-log.log', 'a'))
print = logger.info

def wrike_test():
    code = requests.get(wrike_url+"oauth2/authorize?client_id="+wrike_clientId+"&response_type=code")
    print(code.status_code)
    token_url = wrike_url+"oauth2/token/"
    access_token = requests.post(token_url, data = {'client_id' : wrike_clientId,
                                                    'client_secret' : wrike_clientSecret,
                                                    'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
                                                    'code' : str(code.status_code)
                                                    })
def main():
    wrike_test()
main()
```

I get a 404 error.

Could not tag wrike as it required more rep.

Comment: Try printing the exact URL you are sending, and then paste that into a browser manually before blaming your code.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, do you mean the token URL? not sure how to print the entire URL with parameters passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easier way to do it after reading online for a while. This method does require you to have a permanent token which can be obtained while setting up the wrike app.

```
import requests

# Remember to make sure you are using the correct api version
# The current one is v4
# here are instructions on how to check your version
# https://developers.wrike.com/documentation/api/methods/api-version
api_version = 4
url = f"https://www.wrike.com/api/v{api_version}/tasks"

headers = {
    'authorization': "bearer <your permanent token here>",
    }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

First check the service exists and you are generating the URL you expect.

```
string_to_send = wrike_url+"oauth2/authorize?client_id="+wrike_clientId+"&response_type=code"    
print(string_to_send)
code = requests.get(string_to_send)
```

Paste the printed result into a browser to check that you get the response you expect before blaming your code.

Comment: Check the post URL in the same way

Comment: unable to get the post url working. I constructed the following URL to send 
`wrike_url+"oauth2/token/client_id="+wrike_clientId+"&client_secret="+wrike_clientSecret+"&grant_type=authorization_code"+"&code="+str(code.status_code)` but it does not seem to work

Comment: I dont think its the code. When I run the url to get the code, there is an extra step which asks to ALLOW or DENY access and that is the part (maybe) API is unable to handle.